# How would a post-human civilization integrate a modern society?

Tags: internal-consistency, society, technology, culture, trans-humanism

**Background Information**

In my scenario, humans have advanced to the point to where they are god-like machines barely recognizable to the humans of today. With the appearance of their bodies being the only thing that is similar. (And even then, the new human bodies can be quite different due to augmentation.)

They are capable of living for as long as they have sufficient energy and they can manipulate their virtual and physical home world's at will. They also tend to expand by converting planets into giant quantum computers and building Dyson swarms around lonely stars.

And despite being fairly secular in view, they are also quite spiritual, as they view themselves as higher celestial beings for having passed the Great Filter. And in the stories setting they are the first and only species to have ever evolved to sail the stars.

This spirituality has led post-humanity onto a quest of uplifting and analoging any and all life that they come across in order to ease what they see as the innate suffering of the flesh.

**Question**

Now that the background and setting are filled out, I can get to the core of my question, which is how would an advance human society such as this integrate a lesser one like ours?

And since I'm often told to be more specific (and because I think it's more interesting), I would like to use our present day Earth as the basis for the society that is being integrated into the post-human one.

**Things to consider:** 
(if this part broadens it too much then please ignore)

- How would the differing and sometimes warring states be dealt with during and post-integration? What about prejudices such as racism?
- Would the advance civilization use spies to ease them into it or just show up and rip it off like a bandaid?

It should also be noted that post-humanity wants the integration to be the least stressful and painful for the integrating species as possible. People are also not forced into being integrated. It's more of a strongly encouraged offer.

Comment: What do you mean by "integrate"? And why shouldn't they just coexist?

Comment: @Mołot By integrate, I'm thinking along the lines of say how a modern country would introduce an uncontacted tribe to the modern world and easing them into it.

Comment: @Mołot And they can coexist. It's just that the post-humans view it as a violation of their moral code to not at the very least give others the chance to end what they perceive as the suffering of being biological.

Comment: Just like the Borg?

Comment: @JoeKissling No idea, as I haven't actually watched or read that much Star Trek. I'm assuming the borg are more violent than these post-humans though and that the motives are still different.

Comment: It was a joke, the borg just assimilates you, there is no coexisting, no society left.

Comment: @JoeKissling Sorry for my misunderstanding

Comment: The Star Trek point seems actually quite apt. Lots of discussion there about how a more-developed society can/should ethically assist lower civilizations. In this particular case, if the super-advanced humans are still humans (with all our faults and drives), it probably won't go well for the poor backward Earthlings. Even worse, the super-humans have a dogma or ideology that seems to *encourage* them to abuse and exploit lesser civs. Not pretty.

Comment: To me, the philosophy of your civilization doesn't make sense. On one side, they consider as superior and consider biological bodies to be a Really Bad Thing. On the other side, they are willing to give people a choice. If they are willing to give people a choice, then it means they must accept idea that their idea of "perfection" might not be correct. Which is not what you seem to describe them as.

Comment: I would recommend reading/watching Childhood's End, as it is really close to what you are describing. Especially the first arc is exactly about problems you describe.

Comment: Sounds a bit like the Amplitur in the Damned Trilogy.

Comment: I don't think I'll ever understand this websites ever changing opinion of what is broad or specific.

Comment: @Euphoric I don't think they would have to accept that their way might not be correct. They view themselves as superior yes, but they also value sentient life and value free will. If a person rejects what they see as salvation, then to them they would merely view it as suicide. They may not  like the decision but they will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they have such God-Like powers, and wish to end suffering, let them do it. First rule of business: Nobody is allowed to make a profit, gain an advantage, or gain pleasure by intentionally causing harm to another person, physically or financially, anywhere on Earth. I'd include the prevention of intentional mental cruelty; but I'd make a distinction between that and just hurt feelings. (e.g. a teen may feel despair if their crush rejects them; but that is not their crush causing them pain because they like to see others in pain.)

They **can** make a profit, gain pleasure, get rich, etc by mutual unforced agreement: think along the lines of the entertainment industry, a bunch of people can make a movie, charge admission, and earn a fortune; but nobody is ever forced to see or pay for such a movie. Or sports game, or concert. Same for novels, Stephen King got rich writing without anyone ever being forced to pay him for a book. Same for many chefs, teachers, etc. The entire economy can be this way and it will work just fine.

By what mechanism do the aliens effect this change? They are god-like, we don't have to understand it. Say AI like sensors the size of molecules are inhaled by every person on Earth and prevent fingers from pulling triggers, arms from completing a blow in anger, the crimes, rapes, murders from happening. They pervade weapons, too: Bombs don't explode, gun's don't fire, missiles won't launch, cars are disabled if drivers are angry enough to try and use them to harm others.

You have the right to do as you wish, without harming others. Suffering is averted. Not only does your *right* to swing your fist end at my nose; your *ability* to do so disappears, and in fact, since that close might be frightening and intimidating, you are unable to get even that close: The anger that makes one person try to resolve the dispute with intimidation, threats and coercion of others is thwarted, every time. So they may say hurtful things but they can't even utter a threat; the AIs understand language and intent just as well as humans and prevent such threats from being uttered, no matter how convoluted: Like oxygen, they are in the brain and can **see** the intent.

As to the question of assimilation: Same answer. The God-like aliens are perfect lie detectors, understand intents perfectly, and once they ask humans to join them, can select those that are sincere. The rest can live out their lives on Earth, still restrained by the AIs, but perhaps a future generation will also have the means to join the aliens in their quest to make the universe a better place.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to do it would be forcing it. Humanity as a whole have very little say in anything. Elites around the World are not about to give up their privilege and power just for the greater good of humanity.

So at the very least you need to collapse major parts of the international economy and deal with the self serving elites. Best way to deal with them would be to eliminate them for the greater good.

Fast and ruthless destroying military capabilities and economies would be best, replacing them immediately with something sustainable while the conversion is going on. Otherwise there may be no survivors of the chaos.

This is how whole civilisations were assimilated in the past here on earth. Destroy the military, destroy the leadership, destroy the economy and you can control the population. The faster you can accomplish the first, the less disruption and danger for the rest. A lot may even welcome it.